# Using Multiple JQuery Scripts

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page in which I need to run multiple JQuery scripts. One is for a light-box image viewer, and the other is to add the masonry-brick layout to my images. Both scripts work great individually, but when they are together, the the light-box won't work. What am I doing wrong?

I have a demo of the problem here:
with masonry: http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/scrapbook.html
without masonry: http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/scrapbook2.html

Click the sunglasses to see the problem.

Here is my source for the one that has both scripts. Notice, I stripped some html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title> Scrapbook </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/scrapbook.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/navbar.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<title>FancyBox 1.3.4 | Demonstration</title>
<script type="text/javascript"    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js">  
<\/script>');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" 
media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        *   Examples - images
        */

        $("a#example1").fancybox();
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-title">
    <p> Colin's Scrapbook </p>
</div>
<div id="new-album-button">
    <div id="btn" class="create-album">
        <p><a href="createalbum.html"> + create album </a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
            <div id="brick" class="event">
        <div class="event-top">
            <img src="http://www.destination360.com/north-
america/us/florida/images/s/south-florida-beaches.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="event-bottom">
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img 
src="http://cbsmiami.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/bill_baggs_beach.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img src="http://www.best-beaches.com/images/best-
florida-vacations/florida-best-vacations.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img src="http://www.destin-florida-
mls.com/images/destin12.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img src="http://www.rachelmarks.com/wp-
content/uploads/2009/10/Beach-Florida.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-title">
            <p> Florida 2012 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="brick" class="moment">
        <a id="example1" href="./example/1_b.jpg"><img alt="example1" 
src="./example/1_b.jpg" /></a>
    </div>  
</div>

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){

var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '#brick'
  });
});

});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What should this code do? <script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js">  
<\/script>');

Comment: Seems they're incompatible?! Your going to have to write your own popup or masonry.

Comment: @lee thats a test to see if Jquery's loaded isn't it, tests to see if the google jquery site is down and defaults to load locally, standard practice. Does raise a good point, your loading Jquery 1.4 and Jquery 1.7?? This seems like a bad idea, if only for efficiencies sake

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors with your JS.

1. On your `$(document).ready(function() {` you forgot to close this tag.
2. You're including 2 instances of jQuery, which are conflicting (and perhaps cancelling out each other).  My suggestion is just to load jQuery 1.7.  I've tested it, and it seems to work fine with Fancybox.

Here is the correct, tested and working code (not, everything is absolute paths since I was testing this locally)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Scrapbook </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/styles/scrapbook.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/styles/navbar.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<title>FancyBox 1.3.4 | Demonstration</title>
<script src="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" 
media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        *   Examples - images
        */
        $("a#example1").fancybox();

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-title">
    <p> Colin's Scrapbook </p>
</div>
<div id="new-album-button">
    <div id="btn" class="create-album">
        <p><a href="createalbum.html"> + create album </a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
            <div id="brick" class="event">
        <div class="event-top">
            <img src="http://www.destination360.com/north-
america/us/florida/images/s/south-florida-beaches.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="event-bottom">
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img 
src="http://cbsmiami.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/bill_baggs_beach.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img src="http://www.best-beaches.com/images/best-
florida-vacations/florida-best-vacations.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img src="http://www.destin-florida-
mls.com/images/destin12.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="event-bottom-pic">
                <img src="http://www.rachelmarks.com/wp-
content/uploads/2009/10/Beach-Florida.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-title">
            <p> Florida 2012 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="brick" class="moment">
        <a id="example1" href="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/example/1_b.jpg"><img alt="example1" 
src="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/example/1_b.jpg" /></a>
    </div>  
</div>
<script src="http://shareit.me/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '#brick'
  });
});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```